# ScrollPosition Synchronization

Tags: attributes

Two separate Panes. Pane-1 with vertical scroll bars and Pane-2 no scroll bars.  Need to sync the scrolling between them.  When scrolling Pane-1 vertically, need to have pane 2 automatically scroll to the same ScrollPosition. Is there a technique I can use? Or, is there a way to acquire Pane-1's scroll position as it is being scrolled and dynamically update Pane-2's position?

Comment: Perhaps someone wrote code for a dynamic grid, scroll bars in subsections of the grid?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [`ScrollPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScrollPosition.html):

> The settings for `ScrollPosition` can be `Dynamic` objects.

This means we can do the following:

```
x = 0;
Pane[
 Pane[200!, 300],
 ImageSize -> {100, 100},
 Scrollbars -> {False, True},
 ScrollPosition -> Dynamic@{0, x}
 ]
Pane[
 Pane[200!, 300],
 ImageSize -> {100, 100},
 Scrollbars -> {False, True},
 ScrollPosition -> Dynamic@{0, x}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Lukas.  Dah! I knew about using ScrollPosition, but only considered it for the initial Pane condition.  The use of Dynamic somehow blew past my brain.  Thank you, this helps a lot.